# main.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\Data\StockItemConfigurationInterface

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3.p1

i face this error

```
    main.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryConfigurationApi\Api\Data\StockItemConfigurationInterface in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Invento...', NULL, 'stockItemConfig...', 'Magento\\Invento...')
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Invento...', NULL, 'qtyLeftChecker', 'Magento\\Invento...')
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#10 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#11 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#14 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Invento...', NULL, 'productQty', 'Magento\\Invento...')
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#17 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Invento...', Array, Array)
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Invento...', Array)
#19 /vendor/magento/framework/App/ActionFactory.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(306): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#21 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Router/Base.php(167): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->matchAction(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Array)
#22 /vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(144): Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#31 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#33 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#34 /pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#35 {main} [] []
```

I would like to ask here if anyone has a suggestion before i give this to a magento development company to solve this for me.

Comment: i have disabled MSI and i think that cause this, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide steps that where you are getting this error.
I am assuming that this error you are getting in API. if that is the case
add preference for the interface in VENDOR/MODULE/etc/di.xml

Comment: I just see it at logs. I don't know what this error can cause in Magento. How can i see which module give this error? Is it any other solution except disable modules one by one?

Comment: 1. first thing try to disable all third party extension modules installed. check if issue is coming. if no then disable one by one to check which module giving error.
2. If yes , then disable all your custom modules created. we can debug just by divide and conquer method.

Comment: i have MSI disabled but i see that in 2.4.3 the modules Magento_InventoryCatalogFrontendUi, Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchBundleProduct, Magento_InventoryCatalogSearchConfigurableProduct
are enabled, Is them part of MSI? maybe this cause the issue?